# Performance of Spring boot project when makes it installed

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I made two programs. One is a Client program that sends UDP Packet to UDP Server and the other is a Server program that receives UDP Packet from UDP Client.

UDP Server is made by Spring boot.
The problem is that there is difference of performance between run in STS(Spring Tools Suite) and run as jar(maven installed).
When I run this program in STS(Run as->Spring boot app), it gets all packets from client. If Client sent 3,000 packets, it gets 3,000 packet. But when I run as jar(maven install), it gets a little of packets about 200-300. Even It's exactly same code.

I don't know why it occurs. Is there any way to build spring boot app or need some option?

Whole code is too large. so I upload connect, send, bind code.

This is Client program

```java
public UdpClient(String[] args) {

    connector = new NioDatagramConnector();
    connector.setHandler(this);
    ConnectFuture connFuture = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress(
            args[0], 6001));
    connFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();

    if(args[1] != null) {
        totalCount = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    }
    if(args[2] != null) {
        count = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    }

    connFuture.addListener(new IoFutureListener<ConnectFuture>() {
        public void operationComplete(ConnectFuture future) {
            if (future.isConnected()) {
                session = future.getSession();
                try {
                    sendData(totalCount, count);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("Not connected...exiting");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void sendData(int totalCount, int count) throws InterruptedException {
    int tempCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {

        try{
            File udpData = new File("udp_data.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(udpData));

            String line;
            int k = 0;
            ArrayList<IoBuffer> bufList = new ArrayList<IoBuffer>();

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] str = line.split(" ");
                IoBuffer buf = IoBuffer.allocate(str.length);

                for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {

                    int hexData = Integer.parseInt(str[j],16);
                    byte hexByte = (byte)hexData;
                    buf.put(hexByte);
                }

                bufList.add(buf);
                buf.flip();
            }

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                session.write(bufList.get(j));

                tempCount++;

                if(j % 100 == 0) {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }
            }

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("oper Time : " + (endTime - startTime));

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total Send Count : " + tempCount);
}
```

and this is server program.

```java
@Service
public class ModBusUdpMina {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ModBusUdpMina.class);

    @Autowired
    private IoHandlerAdapter ioUdpHandlerAdapter;

    @Autowired
    private ProtocolCodecFactory ambProtocolCodecFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void bind() {
        NioDatagramAcceptor acceptor = new NioDatagramAcceptor();
        acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast(\"codec\", new ProtocolCodecFilter(ambProtocolCodecFactory));
        acceptor.setHandler(ioUdpHandlerAdapter);
        acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReuseAddress(true);
        acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReceiveBufferSize(1024*512);
        acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(2048);
        acceptor.getSessionConfig().setIdleTime(IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 10);
        try {
            acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(6001));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing them in the same network environment?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Yes, I tried testing them in the same network. I tested it two ways.

1. Server(My computer), Client(My Computer)
2. Server(My computer), Client(Other computer in the same network)

but result was the same.

Comment: Are U using windows or linux ?

Comment: @Koitoer My Computer is Windows 10. And other computer for test is Ubuntu.

Comment: Could be firewall, I remember when I ran the first time spring-boot windows ask if I need to deactivate firewall for process from STS and also say something similar for JVM, I would start disabling completely the firewall, if not this trend will be interesting.

Comment: @Koitoer You mean firewall makes difference between run is sts and run as jar? I didn't even think about that. I will disable the firewall and retry it and reply again. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Not exactly jvm vs sts, but who knows seems like some networking issue, not platform issue I think

Comment: @Koitoer I tried disabling the firewall and retry it. UnFortunately, it doesn't work. It showed the same result.

Comment: If you use this params with maven to increase the memory of the process java -Xmx2048m -Xms256m -jar spring-boot-app,jar, probably default values for maven process are too low. Also please paste some snippets of code client and server

Comment: I meant mvn command and give to the process more memory

Comment: @Koitoer I tried that option. but it was same. I update the part of the code.   I'm really sorry to be taking your a lot of time to solve this problem. I thank you again.

Comment: did you checked if you are using the same JVM? I have multiple installed and it happened to me in the past that I was executing in STS using 1.8 but on CLI using 1.7 which sometimes makes a difference in how libraries are using functionalities.

Comment: @daniel.eichten I used the same JVM and I am using only 1.8. It's still mysterious.